# how to get List from Webservice in window phone?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, service

i have a code :

```
List<Songs> song;
ServiceBaiHat.MywebserviceSoapClient service = new ServiceBaiHat.MywebserviceSoapClient(); 
service.getListCatalogAsync();

service.getListCatalogCompleted+=service_getListCatalogCompleted;


private void service_getListCatalogCompleted(object sender, ServiceBaiHat.getListCatalogCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Result != null)
  {
    XElement element = XElement.Parse(e.Result.ToString());
    listbaihat = (from p in element.Descendants("songs")
                  select new Songs
                  {
                    name = (string)p.Element("name"),
                    link = (string)p.Element("link"),
                    album = (string)p.Element("album")
                  }).ToList<Songs>();

  }
}
```

now, why have error at element.Descendants("songs")???

Comment: Can you post the XML?

Comment: I don't understand why the type of song is called `Songs` (plural) while the `List<Songs>` is called `song` (singular).  `listbaihat` contains no variable definition... are you missing `var` or did it have a type?

Comment: Without knowing the error you're getting, it could be that element is null or it could be that there is no "songs" descendant.